# nuxt js vendor file is too large

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt 2 with bootstrap vue. My current nuxt.config.js has following modules

- '@nuxtjs/moment',
- '@nuxtjs/axios',
- '@nuxtjs/sitemap',
- 'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
- '@nuxtjs/google-tag-manager',
- 'nuxt-device-detect',

and these packages as plugins,

- vue-carousel
- vue-progressive-image

the vendor.app.js file is 3.23 MB, is there any way to optimize it?

Comment: You could use only needed locales in moment if did not yet

Comment: all locales except en is stripped with @nuxtjs/moment.

Comment: Ok, have you tried to run `yarn build --analyze`?
This should visualize your bundle with webpack-bundle-analyzer

Comment: @ElijahEllanski Thanks for the suggestion. I ran the command and found some unrequired svg fonts. I removed them, but, the vendor file is still big.

Comment: @priosshrsth Did you find any solution to this. I'm also looking for solution to reduce the entrypoint size.